# Configure the Grails event bus scheduler for RxJava 2.x

Tags: events, grails, rx-java2

We are using Grails 4.x with RxJava 2.x plugin (grails-event-rxjava2:4.0.0). We are trying to change the default Io scheduler to a different one. [Documentation](http://async.grails.org/snapshot/guide/index.html) shows how to this for the default event bus implementation, but we cannot change it for RxJava 2

grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
import org.grails.events.bus.*
import java.util.concurrent.*

beans = {
    eventBus(ExecutorEventBus, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))
}
```

For RxJava2 we are supposed to use RxJavaPlugins class, but we don't know how to configure the resources.groovy.

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`RxEventBus`](https://github.com/grails/grails-async/blob/master/grails-events-rxjava2/src/main/groovy/org/grails/events/rxjava2/RxEventBus.groovy) is configured with Java's `ServiceLoader` via a [`src/main/resources/META-INF/services/grails.events.bus.EventBus`](https://github.com/grails/grails-async/blob/master/grails-events-rxjava2/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/grails.events.bus.EventBus) file, using its default constructor with a `Schedulers.io()` scheduler. Since the scheduler attribute is final, the only way I imagine you can achieve what you want is to provide your own implementation:

1. Make `grails-events-rxjava2` a `compileOnly` dependency, otherwise both `RxEventBus` and `YourEventBus` will be found, resulting in an error.
2. Subclass `org.grails.events.rxjava2.RxEventBus`:

   ```
   class YourEventBus extends RxEventBus {
       YourEventBus() {
           super(Schedulers.computation()) //or whatever
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register your custom implementation in a `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/grails.events.bus.EventBus` file.

Comment: Thanks! It also works for the default implementation instead of the proposed solution of the grails documentation